# Getting he/she intuitively right if native language has only gender-neutral pronouns

Tags: personal-pronouns, gender

At times I can speak English fluently enough. The biggest issue bothering me is that when not carefully speaking, I mix 'he' and 'she' pronouns randomly. Example: "Jane's not here today. He's on a holiday."

When writing, I don't have this problem. The reason for this issue is that my native language has only gender-neutral pronouns so my brain is not wired for this kind of thing.

The question is: **How to teach myself to use 'he' and 'she' *automatically* correctly when speaking?**

Comment: Short of something like shock therapy, I'm not sure there's any magic "trick" that will make you _automatically_ remember the correct pronoun. This is like asking, "How can I automatically put my fingers on the right frets while playing guitar?" or, "How can I automatically hit the right letters on my computer keyboard?" Some things are only learned through practice.

Comment: I'm not really looking for a magic trick. I've been using English in my workplace for 6 years or so, and despite speaking English almost daily, this particular issue doesn't seem to get any easier.

Comment: I don't think there is any way except "practice a lot".  English is really pretty simple this way: men and boys are "he", women and girls are "she".  Animals, maybe you call "he" or "she" if they're kind of "personal" or it actually makes a difference to the sentence.  If you feel like English is tough, be glad you're not learning German or Spanish, in which every single object has a gender, or [Japanese, where you have to learn how to pluralize just about every single thing differently](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese/count-in-japanese/)...

Comment: My suggestion to you, Regel, would be to start from something you're comfortable with. English has something called the [Singular They](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they) which you can use as a stop-gap while you start familiarizing yourself with the proper gender-specific pronouns. When you're not sure, fall back on the Singular They, and when you are sure, use the appropriate gender-specific pronoun. That way, you can ease yourself into it with practice.

Comment: @stangdon, English is plenty hard enough. Talk about pluralization: do we just add an -s (tree => trees)? Or perhaps we need -es (box => boxes)? Then again, might we need to add -en (ox => oxen)? Or are we talking about an irregular noun (nucelus => nuclei; goose => geese)? What about the irregular nouns that need an additional suffix (leaf => leaves)? Or those nouns that just ignore all of that and use the same form and no suffixes regardless of count (1 deer => 27 deer; 1 sheep => 4028 sheep)?

Comment: @Sina - That suggestion should really be an answer. It's quite good. Instead of trying to get it right in day-to-day conversation, pick a time where you just practice gender pronouns.

Comment: @Sina - I'd rather upvote your answer than your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Women have curves. So does the letter S.

Problem solved.

Similar to the method suggested by Sina, you can get a photo or two of your favorite women and write *She* on them. If you need to, you can get a couple of photos of your favorite men and write *He* on them. Study the photos each day. You can do this with your photos of friends and family.

For added practice, sit  on the bus or whatever and connect each person with *she* or *he*.

Answer (score 4):

Train your mind. Once one of my Profs, [Dr. Ahmad Jamali](https://ca.linkedin.com/in/ahmad-jamali-98861498), adviced us to go stand on a crowded street and start practcing he, she pronounes. He said just look at the people walking by and say he if you see a male and she if you see a female. I never had this problem so never tried it. But you can give it a try if you like.